# Is Inline SQL hard coding?

Tags: sql

I have heard some strong developers say that "inline SQL in and of itself is not evil".  I do not understand how inline SQL is acceptable.  To me its just like hard coding.  Many a developer would scoff in my face for putting a connection string in the code vs a config file.  So why is it that "SELECT value1,value2 FROM TABLE" is perfectly acceptable in compiled code?

Comment: Next they'll tell you you shouldn't hardcode variable names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a lot of **coupling** between a **database query** and the **code that surrounds it**. For example, a query might fetch first name and last name for a particular user from a database, and then create an XML file containing the first name and last name.

If you put the database query somewhere else (e.g. config file) it might seem like you've increased configurability and flexibility. However, if you want to actually change it, say add a field called "age" to the XML file, you can't just change the query alone, you need to change the code writing the XML file. So in fact you've replaced the problem of having to change one piece of code, with the problem of having to change two things (code and configuration), and the danger that they might not be consistent, and you haven't gained any extra flexibility.

(If it seems like one can just write generic code to take all database fields and put them in the XML file, consider the case where age is stored as the birth year in the database, and you have to do computation to create the age.)

Comment: I would posit this as an example of why the database interface needs to be treated explicitly.  By putting the SQL close to the usage, you've improved impact analysis, but more tightly coupled the database.  If the database usage is changing, I would make that explicit and version your database services interface, so that a new "database method" (i.e. a stored procedure) provides new information without breaking the old method. Similarly to how you might manage a COM component's interface over a life-cycle. This also improves impact analysis, since your services interface is well inventoried.

Comment: I see the database as part of the system. If I put a new release into production, I update the code and run DB migrations as necessary. If I need to create a new feature, I develop the new code and new DB together. To do otherwise is to add complexity, and I'd need to know I'm solving a real problem before I add complexity (examples of such a real problem - many systems are accessing the same database, or multiple installations with different database schema versions, or something like that.)

Comment: I see your point.  MVC applications combined with the Entity-Framework remove quite a bit of coupling.  I believe entity-framework generates a little in-line SQL behind the scenes. Perhaps this new technology will turn, or at least redefine the way we look at inline SQL.

Comment: While premature separation in the name of configurability is indeed bad, there is another problem. By subordinating one language into simple strings nested in another, you have thrown away all of the available tooling for that language and you can not get it back. This strikes me as a poor tradeoff.

Answer (score 6):

When I see the length programmers go to just to avoid simple queries like:

```
select * from products where productid in (1,2) and productactive = 1
```

or:

```
select * from products where not exists (
    select * from order_lines where products.id = order_lines.productid)
```

Then I always wonder what their real goal is.  Because it can't be simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is code, it's just not the same programming language as the rest of your code. If you need to change the SQL, you usally always need to change the code dealing with that SQL, data and database schema as well. The SQL shouldn't vary between installation.

If you add a column, changing the SQL isn't enough, you'll need to change code handling that column as well. Pretty much any change to the database schema and SQL, just changing the SQL is not enough.

A connection string on the other hand is configuration, not code.

(And yes, there's exceptions to all of this, if you're creating a general purpose reporting tool, you'll need to engineer that so the SQL can be "configurable")

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries are code, not configuration.

It is useful in an agile environment to use stored procedures on a system like SQL Server where they are dynamically compiled, as you can often fix or workaround an application problem by patching the stored proc.

But it is still code.

Answer (score 2):

Another distinction (aside from code vs. configuration) is that a connection string is probably used all over your codebase whereas a SQL query is more likely to be coupled to a specific class or method. Therefore, if you subscribe to "Don't Repeat Yourself", you'd definitely benefit from centralizing the connection string but would likely gain nothing from moving the SQL string to a different location.

That being said, some of the most elegant solutions involve avoiding SQL strings entirely by using Hibernate or another ORM, but that's a different topic.

Comment: "That being said, some of the most elegant solutions involve avoiding SQL strings entirely by using Hibernate or another ORM, but that's a different topic." maybe it _is_ off topic, but 6 years later with increasing numbers of professional developers throwing away tools without fully examining the tradeoffs, it bears reminding. +1

Answer (score 1):

"SELECT value1,value2 FROM TABLE" in compiled code was the essence of so called [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Since LINQ was released inline SQL is no longer acceptable in vast majority of cases...

Comment: When we did high-volume tests, `CommandText` with SQL was over 10 times faster than Linq2Sql.  It turns out that Linq2Sql compiles assemblies on the fly, which makes it scale really badly. (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: I'll correct the downvote, but also note that LINQ (against tables and views) effectively produces SQL with many of the drawbacks of inline SQL, including the security management issues of dealing with direct table access by requiring rights to be managed at the table level instead of the EXEC level.

Comment: @Andomar, LINQ is slower but not by that margin... if it is that slower in your solution you might want to check 10 Tips to Improve your LINQ to SQL Application Performance [http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html]. At the same time, gains in code maintainability and manageability offset any perfomnce loss most of the time...

Comment: @kzen: In our performance test, it was 10x slower.  One of the tips mentioned is `CompiledQuery`, which we tried, and that ran just 20% slower.  However, the complexity of `CompiledQuery` is almost funny when you compare it to the elegance of a select statement.

Comment: The 10x performance loss is what you'll see if you run the query just once, as that first time it'll generate an assembly on the fly. subsequent use of the same linq query will reuse that assembly, so it should only be the very first time a of a particular query that takes the performance hit

Comment: @nos: Unfortunately, it caches only a limited number of assemblies. If you use more than 10 LINQ queries, you'll see the application  generating assemblies during its entire lifespan

Comment: Even if it was 10x slower, is that enough in your specific application? Maintainability, toolability, and readability all matter more until you can empirically demonstrate that you need the given query to run 10x faster in order to implement your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I've made systems where all the SQL is in stored procedures and the names of the stored procedures are themselves not even stored in the program, but in the app.config.

This means then not only can stored procedures be patched, but different customers can use different procedures.

The database services interface provided to the application(s) is thus part of the system design.

A drawback of having any SQL in a client application at all (and this includes table-based ORMs and LINQ) is that you have very little explicit security interface.  With stored procedures, there is a single GRANT - EXEC.  With tables or even views, the ORM will need SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE for whatever SQL is generated by the tool or stored in the application.  Taking an inventory of the rights needed for the system to properly run and being able to audit is much more difficult than having a good solid layer of stored procedures (and, to some extent, read-only views) which everything goes through.

So I would say that "SELECT value1, value2 FROM TABLE" is not acceptable in client code, because every user who would potentially execute that statement needs to have SELECT on those two column from a base table, and that is hard to manage, even with roles.

Comment: If you need to rely on the database level security, you have other problems IMO.

Comment: @Brook In many environments, having the application login have carte blanche makes auditing very difficult.  Having users accountable all the way through the database layer is a good way to handle that (also in the multi-modal case, where you may have web apps, rich apps, reporting applications - all hitting the database or a layer above it).

Comment: Service Layer + AOP will give you much more detail auditing in those cases.  If you have different apps hitting the same db directly, that's a whole different problem.  Connection string sharing is not a SOA strategy.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is to think of table names and column names as part of the database's "public" interface. That's how databases implement physical data independence. And updatable views implement logical data independence, to some degree.